# MySQL examining too many rows when WHERE clause has more than one IN

Tags: mysql, where-clause, explain

I'm currently using MySQL 5.6.10.

My actual query is more complicated, but here is a simple way to reproduce the problem.  I know the query below is useless (select id from x where id in (select id from x...)), but it proves my point.

I created this table:

```
CREATE  TABLE test (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Then ran this command 5 times - it created 50 rows in the table:

```
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null);
```

And then ran this explain:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM test WHERE 
       id in (SELECT id FROM test WHERE id < 5);
```

And got this:
[image: 4 Rows]

Which makes perfect sense to me.   But then if I add an OR to the WHERE clause with another IN, like this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM test WHERE 
       id IN (SELECT id FROM test WHERE id < 5)
    OR id IN (SELECT id FROM test WHERE id > 45);
```

suddenly MySQL is looking at all 50 rows:
[image: 50 Rows]

I know that the query could be re-written as `SELECT id FROM test WHERE id < 5 OR id > 45`, or a UNION etc, again, that's not the point.  The point is MySQL is examining far too many rows.

If I run a FLUSH STATUS / SHOW STATUS LIKE "Handler%" on the first query, this is what I get:

```
Handler_read_key 5
Handler_external_lock 4
Handler_read_next 4
Handler_read_first 1
```

But if I do that to the second query, I get:

```
Handler_read_key 99
Handler_write 9
Handler_external_lock 6
Handler_read_next 59
Handler_read_first 2
```

Why the big difference?  I wonder if it is the optimizer, and if so, is there some option I can include in the query that will prevent this "optimization"?  This has real practical implications for a query I'm developing.  Instead of examining only a few hundred rows, MySQL is examining 120,000.

Comment: because you are doing ins bumptious and that means you do not benefit from joins but are suffering the wrath of exponential woe from ... as stated, using ins !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, RDBMS are not able to optimise subqueries as well as they can optimise proper table joins.  As documented under [Rewriting Subqueries as Joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/rewriting-subqueries.html) (emphasis added):

> Sometimes there are other ways to test membership in a set of values than by using a subquery. Also, on some occasions, it is not only possible to rewrite a query without a subquery, but ***it can be more efficient to make use of some of these techniques rather than to use subqueries***. One of these is the `IN()` construct:
>
> For example, this query:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM t2);
> ```
>
> Can be rewritten as:
>
> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id;
> ```

In your abstract case (i.e. ignoring other obvious improvements one would make to this query in reality):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM   test t1
  JOIN test t2 USING (id)
  JOIN test t3 USING (id)
WHERE  t2.id < 5
    OR t3.id > 45;
```

For which the execution plan is:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| ID | SELECT_TYPE | TABLE |  TYPE  | POSSIBLE_KEYS |   KEY   | KEY_LEN |       REF        | ROWS |                   EXTRA                   |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | range  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY |       4 | (null)           |    9 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY |       4 | db_2_129b4.t1.id |    1 | Using index; Distinct                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY |       4 | db_2_129b4.t1.id |    1 | Using index; Distinct                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/129b4/1/1).